# DUVIDA EM SQL -TRANSFORMAR LINHAS EM COLUNAS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Tenho essa seguinte `query`, ela traz pro mesmo produtos 3 linhas de resultado, queria que esses resultados fossem retornados em colunas, como fazer?

```
SELECT CODPROD, EMB 
FROM TABELA
WHERE PRODUTO = 2
```

essa pesquisa traz o seguinte:

```
CODPROD | EMBALAGEM
      2 |       1X1
      2 |       1X2
      2 |       1X3
```

Queria que trouxesse assim:

```
      2 | 1X1 | 1X2 | 1X3
```

Comment: Tente explicar melhor por favor

Comment: essa pesquisa traz o seguinte:

CODPROD, EMBALAGEM
2                      |      1X1
2                      |      1X2
2                      |      1X3


QUERIA QUE TROUXESSE ASSIM:

2                      |      1X1  | 1X2 | 1X3

Comment: Cara, me desculpe, mas não estou conseguindo entender... Tente, literalmente, desenhar ou dar um exemplo mais claro do que precisa, posta ele como parte da pergunta por favor

Comment: Ao que entendi, tu precisa que retorne um array, exemplo: `Array[2]=> "1X1", "1X2", "1X3"`, desta forma?

Comment: acredito que sim, que ele retorne em uma linha só o resultados dos outros em colunas

Answer (score 2):

Se a versão do seu `Oracle` realmente é a `11g` utilize a função `LISTAGG`:

```
SELECT CODPROD,
       LISTAGG(EMB, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EMB) AS EMBALAGEM
  FROM TABELA
 WHERE PRODUTO = 2
 GROUP BY CODPROD
```

---

> [`LISTAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)
>
> For a specified measure, `LISTAGG` orders data within each group specified in the `ORDER BY` clause and then concatenates the values of the measure column.

Em tradução livre:

> Para uma coluna especificada, o `LISTAGG` ordena os dados dentro de cada grupo especificado na cláusula `ORDER BY` e concatena os valores da coluna.

Comment: Mas ai ele concatena tudo em um campo só, queria que fosse em campos distintos, entende?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius dinamicamente é bem complicado de conseguir

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a função `PIVOT` para trazer suas linhas em colunas:

Exemplo:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 1 codigo, 'Carro' nome FROM dual UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2 codigo, 'Moto' nome FROM dual UNION ALL 
        SELECT 3 codigo, 'Avião' nome FROM dual )    
PIVOT
(
 MAX(codigo) FOR nome IN ('Carro' Carro,'Moto' Moto,'Avião' Avião)
)
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado query]

veja rodando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0b05/1).

Mais informações sobre o assunto poderá encontrar [aqui](http://www.mhavila.com.br/topicos/bd/consulta_pivo.html).

Uma opção mais avançada, seria criar uma função que execute o `SQL` de forma dinâmica e retorne um `CURSOR`, quando você não sabe os valores que podem retornar...

Seguem um exemplo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_linhas_para_tabelas RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS

  sqlqry CLOB;
  cols   CLOB;
  TYPE t_ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
  c t_ref_cursor;

BEGIN

  SELECT listagg('''' || nome || ''' as "' || nome || '"', ',') within GROUP(ORDER BY nome)
    INTO cols
    FROM (SELECT 1 codigo, 'Carro' nome
            FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 2 codigo, 'Moto' nome
            FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 3 codigo, 'Avião' nome
            FROM dual);

  sqlqry := 'select * from
             (
                SELECT 1 codigo, ''Carro'' nome FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 2 codigo, ''Moto'' nome FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 3 codigo, ''Avião'' nome FROM dual
             )
             pivot
             (
               Max(codigo) for nome in (' || cols || ')
             )';


  OPEN c FOR sqlqry;
  RETURN c;

END;
```

Comment: usei o pivot e fiquei com uma duvida, quando eu não souber o resultados das linhas coloco o que?
select * from ( select EMBALAGEM as "EMBALAGEM", CODPROD from TAB_EMBALAGEM t WHERE CODPROD = 15250 ) pivot ( MAX(EMBALAGEM) for EMBALAGEM in ('1X12' as "EMB1",'1X6' "EMB2",'UNIDADE' "EMB3") )

Comment: Complementei com mais uma forma de fazer...

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa utilizar o **PIVOT**, ele irá transformar linhas em colunas, por exemplo:

```
Select CODPROD
         , [1] as coluna_um
         , [2] as coluna_dois
         , [3] as coluna_tres
from TABELA pivot (Embalagem for Emb ([1],[2],[3])) p
order by 1;
```

Você terá que ter 3 valores, uma para a primeira coluna, no caso o **CODPROD**, outra para as outras colunas no caso a **EMB**, e a outra para trazer o valor do **CODPROD** x **EMB**, no caso acredito que seja a **EMBALAGEM**.

Comment: usei o pivot e fiquei com uma duvida, quando eu não souber o resultados das linhas coloco o que? 

`select * from (
   select EMBALAGEM as "EMBALAGEM", CODPROD
   from TAB_EMBALAGEM t WHERE CODPROD = 15250
)
pivot 
(
   MAX(EMBALAGEM)
   for EMBALAGEM in ('1X12' as "EMB1",'1X6' "EMB2",'UNIDADE' "EMB3")
)
order by 1`

Comment: Geralmente você precisa saber o resultado das colunas, por exemplo você quer trazer os produtos x as vendas por mês, ai você vai mapear os meses em colunas (um ano seria 12 colunas), pois qual é o real sentido de sua analise? O que você precisa analisar transformando linhas em colunas? você irá criar algum relatório?

Comment: Se for um relatório em excel você não precisa nem transformar as linhas em colunas, mas sim criar uma tabela dinamica com esse resultado e colocar as linhas em colunas, precisamos saber o proposito final.

Comment: É sim um relatorio que preciso criar. Tenho mais de 6.000 produtos, não tenho como saber o resultado de cada linha para transformar em coluna.

Comment: Como você irá criar um relatório com 6000 colunas? Não é mais fácil extrair a base e tratar os dados com uma dinamica no excel, ou um power bi?

Comment: O relatório que vou criar teria que mostrar todos os produtos e quantas embalagens ele tem, então imagina ai ter que referenciar embalagem por embalagem no pivot? Não tem como, não tem algo mais automático?

Comment: A unica maneira que eu conheço é você fazer o seu bi, como o excel e power bi coletar a consulta, ou se conectar a consulta ou a view do banco de dados, e ela fazer essa geração automática de colunas. Eu já utilizei algumas vezes o pivot e o unpivot e sempre utilizei colunas fixas, não faz muito sentido você criar colunas infinitas, principalmente pela dificuldade do usuário final com a leitura dos dados.

Comment: Consegui criando uma view.

Comment: Compartilhe essa informação com a gente.

Comment: ficou assim: 
`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EMB_LINHA AS
SELECT codprod,
           embalagem || '-' || unidade                                     AS emba,
      
           ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY codprod ORDER BY embalagem)    AS linha
      FROM TABELA
     WHERE 1 = 1
     order by emba`